"From" name is not displayed in Gmail when sending an email via Nylas API?
I am trying to send an email via the Nylas API, and I want the sender's name to be displayed in Gmail. However, only the email address appears in the "From" field, and the name is missing.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
const sentMessage = await nylas.messages.send({
    identifier: 'identifier',
    requestBody: {
        from: [{ email: userSender?.email, name: userSender?.firstName + ' ' + userSender?.lastName }],
        to: [{ email: userRecipient?.email, name: userRecipient?.firstName + ' ' + userRecipient?.lastName }],
        subject: message.subject,
        body: message.content,
        attachments: attachments
    },
});

I expect the "From" field in the email to display both the name and email address (e.g., John Doe john.doe@example.com), but only the email is displayed when the email is received in Gmail.
What I've Tried:

I verified that userSender.firstName and userSender.lastName are not null.
I tried setting the replyTo field as well, but it didn’t fix the issue.
I reviewed Nylas documentation, and it seems like the structure is correct for sending the "from" name.

